# How to enable SSO in Apache Knox?

Tags: apache

I'm working to enable SAML authentication in Apache Knox for our client. Currently I'm facing few issues after setting up SSO related config in KNOX.

On accessing the YarnUI after starting the gateway, The browser gets redirected to the Identity provider URL -> asks for the login credentials -> on submitting the user is getting authenticated but the application gets landed to https://emr-knox-webui-dev.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446 and throws page not found error.

I'm seeing the SAML request sent and SAML response getting received but it gets landed to an invalid page after authentication. I'm unable to figure out the page to land after authentication.

Our Client uses : Ping Federate Identity provider. Listed below the configurations setup and also attached screen shots for better understanding.

### IDP -> Config

Entity ID - https://emr-knox-webui-dev.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true&client_name=SAML2Client
TargetURL - https://emr-knox-webui-dev.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446 (I'm not sure the target URL is valid, I suspect the page is getting redirected to this link after auth)

### KnoxSSO.xml

```
<topology>
   <gateway>
     <provider>
         <role>federation</role>
         <name>pac4j</name>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <param>
          <name>pac4j.callbackUrl</name>
          <value>https://emr-knox-webui-dev.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso</value>
         </param>

         <param>
           <name>clientName</name>
           <value>SAML2Client</value>
         </param>

         <param>
           <name>saml.identityProviderMetadataPath</name>
           <value>/tmp/preprod_metadata_SP.xml</value>
         </param>

         <param>
           <name>saml.serviceProviderMetadataPath</name>
           <value>/tmp/preprod_metadata_SP.xml</value>
         </param>

         <param>
           <name>saml.serviceProviderEntityId</name>
           <value>https://emr-knox-webui-dev.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?pac4jCallback=true&amp;client_name=SAML2Client</value>
         </param>
     </provider>
     <provider>
         <role>identity-assertion</role>
         <name>Default</name>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
     </provider>
   </gateway>

   <service>
       <role>KNOXSSO</role>
       <param>
         <name>knoxsso.cookie.secure.only</name>
         <value>true</value>
      </param>
      <param>
        <name>knoxsso.token.ttl</name>
        <value>100000</value>
      </param>
      <param>
         <name>knoxsso.redirect.whitelist.regex</name>
         <value>^https?:\/\/(emr-knox-webui-dev\.us-west-2\.elb\.amazonaws\.com|localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|::1):[0-9].*$</value>
      </param>
   </service>
</topology>
```

### gate1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<topology>
  <gateway>
    <provider>
        <role>federation</role>
        <name>SSOCookieProvider</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <param>
            <name>sso.authentication.provider.url</name>
            <value>https://emr-knox-webui-dev-1021294088.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8446/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso</value>
        </param>
    </provider>
    <provider>
        <role>identity-assertion</role>
        <name>Default</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </provider>
  </gateway>
  <service>
      <role>YARNUI</role>
      <url>http://ip-10-89-71-228.vpc.internal:8088</url>
  </service>
</topology>
```

Comment: Hi, the configuration you have provided is invalid, you are using the same metadata to describe your Service Provider and your Identity Provider. Unsure whether that is the cause of your problem but it certainly won't help.